# Querying ElasticSearch with Python Requests

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, python-requests

,I am not quite able to retrieve the results when I try to query ElasticSearch using python requests. Here is my code:

```
json_data = updateJson(sys.argv[1])

headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'application/json'}

elastic_url ='https://localhost:9200/logstash-kafka-wga-blueid-\*/_search'

query = json.dumps(json_data)

response = requests.get(elastic_url, data = query, auth=('xxx','xxx'), verify=False, headers = headers)

print response.text
```

I always get the following output:

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":0,"successful":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}
```

But if I try to use the following CURL command, I get the right results. In the above code json_data, reads the json from abc.json file.  Is there something incorrect in the above code?

```
curl -X GET -k -u xxx:xxx https://localhost:9200/logstash-kafka-wga-blueid-\*/_search -d @temporaryRundeckReport.json
```

Here is my updateJson() method:

```
def updateJson(fileName):
with open(fileName, 'r') as file:
    json_data = file.read()
    json_data = json_data.replace('%X-FORWARDED-HOST%', sys.argv[2]);
    json_data = json_data.replace('%TIME%', sys.argv[3]);
    json_data = json_data.replace('%INTERVAL%', sys.argv[4]);

with open('temporaryRundeckReport.json', 'w+') as file:
    os.chmod('temporaryRundeckReport.json',0o777)
    file.write(json_data)
    return json_data
```

Comment: What is the query you pass on the command line? Any reason you're not using [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)?

Comment: I pass the name of file "abc.json" from where it reads the json.

Comment: And what's in `abc.json`? What does `updateJson()` do?

Comment: I have added that method in the original post.

Comment: I am using the exact json_object stored in temporaryRundeckReport.json via requests module. Why should this modify the results?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you also changed your `curl` line. I think the issue is that you use `requests.get(data=...)` instead of `json=`. Your data gets parsed and sent as form data. You can try posting to https://requestb.in/ with both methods and see the difference live.

Comment: No, that's not it since you do `json.dumps()`. But https://requestb.in/ should probably help solve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to escape star `*` in python version (remove slash):

```
elastic_url = 'https://localhost:9200/logstash-kafka-wga-blueid-*/_search'
```

But also, I would recommend using the [python client library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) instead of `requests`.

Comment: But my index in elasticsearch contains "*" character. I figured out that I can define it as follows: 'https://localhost:9200/logstash-kafka-wga-blueid-\\*/_search'

Comment: @akashag26 I don't mean to remove the `*` - I mean that you don't need the slash before `*` (use `...blueid-*` instead of `..blueid-\*`). The slash is needed to escape the star in shell, but it is not needed when you put the url into python variable.